# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Now I write my issue on stackoverflow, because searching the web doesnt bring any solution. Although there are many RoutingError questions and answers, but nothing interesting for me.

This is my error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/kwiki/download/thumbnails/4687717/IP49120-low.jpg"):
```

In my controller I fetch a HTML page from an other server.
This HTML page includes images and links.

The view renders this HTML page well, but without the images.
Where and how can I take care to render also these images?
Where and how can I **replace** the image href
http://**localhost:3000**/kwiki/download/thumbnails/4687717/IP49120-low.jpg
with 
http://**example.com**/kwiki/download/thumbnails/4687717/IP49120-low.jpg?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To modify the HTML page you fetch, you could use [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/).  This replaces mailto: links with the text of the link.  Using a suitable regex you could do something similar to change the image URLs.

```
 doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.example.com'))
 doc.css("a").each do |a|
   unless a['href'].present? && a['href'].starts_with?('mailto:')
     a.replace(a.content)
   end
 end
```